# Private Static Constexpr Member Variable is Inaccessible in Main?

Tags: c++, class, static, constants

In my Environment class I have a private static member variable:

```cpp
class Environment {
public:
    // ...

private:
    std::vector<Part> objects;
    Color background_color;
    
    //ERROR:
    static constexpr Color default_background_color = Color({ 210, 210, 210 });
};
```

And in main I am trying to access that variable:

```
int main() {
    // ERROR: 'member "Environment::default_background_color" is inaccessible'
    Environment environment(0.1, Environment::default_background_color); 
}
```

So my question is, what is wrong and how do I make a const static variable that I can access outside of the Environment class?

Comment: Make it `public`. If you only want it to be accessible for purposes of providing a default value to the constructor, write a constructor that takes a single `double` for its argument and then uses `default_background_color` to delegate to the two-argument constructor.

Comment: I see no static variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data member is declared `private` (and NOT `static`, BTW), so it is simply not accessible to any code outside of the class.

If you want `main()` to access the member, either:

- declare the member as `public` (and `static`):

```cpp
class Environment {
public:
    Environment(double air_density, Color background_color);
    ...
    static constexpr Color default_background_color = Color({ 210, 210, 210 });
    ...
};
```

```cpp
int main() {
    Environment environment(0.1, Environment::default_background_color); // OK
    ...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2XPJf0)

- declare `main()` as a `friend` of the class:

```cpp
class Environment {
public:
    Environment(double air_density, Color background_color);
    ...
private:
    ...
    static constexpr Color default_background_color = Color({ 210, 210, 210 });

    friend int main();
};
```

```cpp
int main() {
    Environment environment(0.1, Environment::default_background_color); // OK
    ...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/XAUb12)